# The connection inside function not called

Tags: c#, forms, ado.net, database-connection, connection-string

this is my snippet , please help me why the con .open is not working inside the function tabledel

i want to delete the table once i press the button , the connection gets opened for the first time but couldnt open it for the second time inside the function tabledel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace WFA_CREATE_DELETE
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:/Users/Dinesh/Documents/Database3.accdb");
        OleDbDataAdapter ea = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        DataSet dsl;
        DataSet esl;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            dsl = new DataSet();
            con.Open();

            DataTable table2 = con.GetSchema("tables");

            MessageBox.Show("Database Open");

            dataGridView1.DataSource = table2;

            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }

        public void Tabledel()
        {
            int a = 0, d = 0, count, itr;

            count = dataGridView1.RowCount;
            itr = dataGridView1.ColumnCount;

            while (a < count)
            {
                for (d = 0; d < itr; d++)
                {
                    if (dataGridView1.Rows[a].Cells[d].Value.ToString() == textBox1.Text)
                    {

                        MessageBox.Show("table exists");
                        esl = new DataSet();
                        string vsql = "drop table '" + textBox1.Text + "'";
                        ea = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(vsql, con);
                        OleDbCommand cmdea = new OleDbCommand(vsql, con);
                        //cmdea.Connection = con;

                        con.Open();
                        cmdea.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        MessageBox.Show("table dropped");
                        con.Close();
                        con.Dispose();
                    }
                }

                a++;
            }
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           Tabledel();


        }

    }
}
```

[link](http://codepad.org/KmNlj83n#comment-zZzdSRrf)

Comment: Please provide sample in the question itself.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you assigned the event handler to the button click event?

Comment: You dispose the connection when you load the form. Apart from this, your code has many more problems. Please paste the code here

Comment: are you getting any error on `con.open()` ?? plz mention that too.

Comment: Next time add your code sample in here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see you get this error:

```
The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.
```

May be you will create (dispose) your connection in somewhere else (except in form class global variable), so I suggest to set connection string explicitly (With recreating connection):

```
con = new OleDbConnection(
      @"PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:/Users/Dinesh/Documents/Database3.accdb");

con.Open();
```

Anyway it wasn't hard to include main part of your code here in SO.

Comment: yeah , so u want me to redefine the con inside the function again?/

Comment: @user1386579, Yes I guess in somewhere this property will set to null or empty. Code size was big and I didn't read it carefully.

Answer (score 0):

The connection object is created when your Form is created. You open, use, close and DISPOSE the connection object in the Form_Load method. Therefore the connection object is gone by the time your button click handler starts to execute.

You have to either create a new connection object in the button click handler, or NOT dispose it in the Form_Load method.

Answer (score 0):

Really hard to decode what your actual problem is, what's causing it and so on, but there are many problems with your code.

First off you shouldn't initialize your `con` object the way you do. Every time you are done using it and call `Dispose`, you'll destroy it. In any case it isn't rebuilt until next time your `Form1` class is initialized. That's probably why you're getting the errors.

A suggestion would be to have a singleton that handles your connection. This leads me to the next point: It's a very bad idea to open new connections inside a loop. If you've made your connection handeler properly, you'd only have to open one connection per call. I'll give you so much better performance, which you'll notice if you have many elements to iterate through.

Next up, your delete statement is subject to SQL injections. You should strongly considder using a way that minimizes the user input to selecting from a list so they can't type in weird queries in your `textBox1.Text`

That's just some of it.. I hope you can use it.

Oh and please, please write a better question. Don't just say "Uh, something doesn't work. Link". Condensate your code and think about what you're asking to make sure it'll be widely understood.

Comment: thanks and i apologize , ll post better question next time , i was bit hurry